# Why is my Luau code not hiding the GUIs that I tried to hide?

Tags: roblox, luau

My code is for hiding some GUIs that I don't want to show. (Note that this is Luau, I can't post to DevForums because I am not a member)

This is what I want to hide:
[Link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMmTg.png)

The code I used was:

```
local Dialog = false
local Confirm = false
local TalkTo = ""

local ConfirmGUI = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.ConfirmGUI.ScreenGui -- Avoiding waste of time writing the full directory and having to fail because it's in PlayerGUI

ConfirmGUI.TextButton.Visible = false
ConfirmGUI.TextButton2.Visible = false
ConfirmGUI.TextLabel.Visible = false
ConfirmGUI.TextTitle.Visible = false
```

The error I keep getting in Developer Console is:

```
  09:04:06.668  ConfirmGUI is not a valid member of PlayerGui "Players.metoplayllol.PlayerGui"  -  Client - LocalScript:6
  09:04:06.668  Stack Begin  -  Studio
  09:04:06.669  Script 'Players.metoplayllol.PlayerGui.DialogGUI.ScreenGui.TextLabel.LocalScript', Line 6  -  Studio - LocalScript:6
  09:04:06.669  Stack End  -  Studio
```

I used a title you can't see because it ruins the fun of the experience.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code

```lua
ConfirmGUI.TextButton.Visible = false
ConfirmGUI.TextButton2.Visible = false
ConfirmGUI.TextLabel.Visible = false
ConfirmGUI.TextTitle.Visible = false
```

Comment: Sensible! But look again...

Comment: Are you 100% sure your UI is named "ConfirmGui"?

Comment: Yes. It's called that, I checked Explorer.

Comment: That can only mean that the UI is being deleted

Comment: What do you mean "The UI is being deleted"?

Comment: Your code is correct but the UI must've been getting deleted. Otherwise there wouldn't been an error. When play testing, look inside your players GUI folder

Comment: When I playtest it, the UI's are still there, which is weird.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:
`script.Parent...Parent:WaitForChild('ConfirmGUI').ScreenGUI`, or flip `ScreenGUI` and `ConfurmGUI`